# Render uses only one texture for all objects in render (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, uv

I'm a real newbie with Blender, so I don't know if some methods I used may be incorrect.
So, for this scene made in the Cycles render engine, I UV mapped the ground mesh to its own texture, then UV mapped all other objects (rocks, trees) to another, single texture.

All looks correct in Rendered preview view, but when I hit F12 to render, all objects seem to be using the ground texture.
I can only assume it's to do with this weird UV mapping technique? How would I go about getting around it?

**Render preview (3D Viewport):**
[image: Render preview (3D Viewport)]

**F12 Rendered scene:**
[image: F12 Rendered scene]
As you can see, parts of all objects have grass covering them and patches of brown dirt.

[Scene Download](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AsRnEDMUKfs8iEQIq3Tiu134eIZF) (includes textures)

Comment: In the "render layers" tab (third tab in the properties panel), there is a material override bound to "ground tex". You need to remove it.